# YouTube API v3 pageToken to generate a random video

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API to generate a page that loads YouTube videos. The stack that I'm using is HTML, CSS, and AngularJS. I want a button that will generate a random video given a search query. The way that I was planning to do this is to use the pageToken attribute.

I noticed that the token "CAEQAA" always returns the second page of search results of the query. And following that, "CAIQAA" gives the next page of search results after that. So this makes me think that these keys are independent of the search query.

However, this might be specific to my search options (one video per page of search results, safe search = strict, etc) even if it is independent of the search query. Is there a way to retrieve all the page tokens possible in a list or some form? This way, I can select a random token from this list to pick a random page of search results and thus a random video.

If I am misunderstanding how this works, please let me know as I am new to using this sort of API. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to your question?

Comment: I never figured out how to do it, and the whole project just kind of went in a different direction. But an answer to this would be nonetheless satisfying for my curiosity as well as helpful for other site visitors who are looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [algorithm](https://github.com/aricearice/youtube-page-token) that can generate a pageToken for any given number in the range [0, 100000] ( you can install with `npm install youtube-page-token`).
With the package you can 
1) fetch the first page of results
2) get a total count
3) get a random number in that total range
4) generate a token for that number
5) plug back into YouTube API